# Seeking feedback on table relationships, general schema design

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema, relations

I'm designing a database for a business that sells tickets to a variety of events worldwide. The app will be built with Rails using PostgreSQL.

Here's what I have so far, [**link**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7D82.jpg) to full size image

[image]

I'm mostly concerned with the relationship between *EVENT_CATEGORIES* / *EVENT_SUB_CATEGORIES* / *TEAMS_ARTISTS* / *COMPETITIONS*.

A typical path for a user to take on the app would be

Sports (event_category)  ---> Football (event_sub_category)  ---> Champions league (competitions)  ---> Arsenal (teams_artists), skipping *competitions* for events without competitions e.g, Concerts.

Will these relationships hold up in a production environment? Is there anything more optimal I'm overlooking? Any other tips in general would be welcome and appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event Category and Sub-Category are classifications of events. They are *your* way of tagging events (i.e. meta-attributes).  The Event itself is a physical-thing/occurence (independent of you)  to which you are attaching these attributes.  Competition and competitors are also physical things- that are associated with the occurrence. When designing, it helps to be aware of what is a physical thing, and what is your design artifact.

I don't think Competition , or Competitors or Performers (if a non-sport event) should depend upon your classification.

** So I would take out the link between sub-category and competition. **

An Event has performers.  A performer can be an individual or a team.
An event will be associated with one or more performers.

A competition like UEFA-CL can be considered a collection of events (*Not the otherway around - as in your model *). Hence competition is independent (or rather, a higher level entity) compared to an event. An Event is kind of like the 'delivery' (or instance) of that competition at a particular time / place.

Hence, Competition --> has multiple (> 0) events --> has multiple (> 0) performers. (This is the way I would look at competitions).  So I would make competition above the Event (in the object heirarchy - not talking of inheritence here)

I can talk about UEFA-CL without referring to a specific event in its set. Competition is composed of (stable) teams.  The competition can span seasons - so you might even have search/drill-down criteria such as Soccer.  You need to setup your production so that you can do analysis easily on your data too. I wouldn't want to bury competition deep inside your heirarchy.